# javascript return function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, return, expression

Can anyone explain why the first of my three sample functions (ref `failFunc()`) should return an undefined value rather than a valid string?

I know I can fix the problem by wrapping the expression in brackets (ref `worksFunc1()`) or placing the result in an intermediate variable (ref `worksFunc2()`) but the fact the first function failed to return a string goes against anything I've experienced in other programming languages.

Fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BloodBaz/zGLmy/

JavaScript:

```
var rs = {};

rs.failFunc = function(n)
{
    var h = "0010";
    var m = "15";
    var s = "12";
    var c = "10";

    return 
        h.substr(h.length - 4) + ":" + 
        m.substr(m.length - 2) + ":" + 
        s.substr(s.length - 2) + "." + 
        c.substr(c.length - 2);
}
rs.worksFunc1 = function(n)
{
    var h = "0010";
    var m = "15";
    var s = "12";
    var c = "10";

    return (
        h.substr(h.length - 4) + ":" + 
        m.substr(m.length - 2) + ":" + 
        s.substr(s.length - 2) + "." + 
        c.substr(c.length - 2));
}
rs.worksFunc2 = function(n)
{
    var h = "0010";
    var m = "15";
    var s = "12";
    var c = "10";

    var res =
        h.substr(h.length - 4) + ":" + 
        m.substr(m.length - 2) + ":" + 
        s.substr(s.length - 2) + "." + 
        c.substr(c.length - 2);
    return res;
}


var res = rs.failFunc();
document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = res;
var res = rs.worksFunc1();
document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = res;
var res = rs.worksFunc2();
document.getElementById('output3').innerHTML = res;
```

HTML:

```
<div id='output1'>output</div>
<div id='output2'>output</div>
<div id='output3'>output</div>
```

OUTPUT:

```
undefined
0010:15:12.10
0010:15:12.10
```

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript syntax is strange. One particularly odd part is that a `return` statement followed by a newline is taken to be `return;`. A `return` without an expression means that to the caller, the return value is `undefined`.

Thus,

```
return 
    h.substr(h.length - 4) + ":" + 
    m.substr(m.length - 2) + ":" + 
    s.substr(s.length - 2) + "." + 
    c.substr(c.length - 2);
```

is effectively the same as

```
return;
    h.substr(h.length - 4) + ":" + 
    m.substr(m.length - 2) + ":" + 
    s.substr(s.length - 2) + "." + 
    c.substr(c.length - 2);
```

[Read all about it in the language spec.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9)

Comment: "Automatic Semicolon Insertion"!?  Thanks for the answer.
I'll have a good read of the spec you've provided and mark your answer in due course.